# Permalink Ajax Issue Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, permalinks

```
var fullpath = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>'
function AjaxRequest(section,divName)
    {

             var pageurl = fullPath+"/ajaxrequest.php?section="+section+"&divName="+divName;         
            //alert(pageurl);   

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                             document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML='';             
                    document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",pageurl,true);
            xmlhttp.send();             

    }
```

I have a Code like that in wordpress which is calling a page using ajax. It is working fine when the page are coming in ID like ?page_id=37 but stop working when I am activating Permalink like /overview/ajaxpage. I am getting 404 pafe error on xmlhttp.readyState. Can any one help me to solve it. I know its a permalink Problem probably this code of ajax is not sufficient for transmuting Permalink.

Comment: If you are getting a "404" page error that means that the value of your pageurl variable is a non existing page. In other words: the problem are not Permalinks, debug the value of the pageurl variable.

Comment: Though I have solved it but don't know if that is the right way. I removed `xmlhttp.status==200` from `if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` and it is working fine now. I removed `xmlhttp.status==200` as I found Status was coming 404 continuously. But if I use default `?page_id` then the status is coming 200. But I really don't know why so I had to remove this condition and now it is really working fine. I hope someone else has better solution rather than that without removing the condition as the condition is needed very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use permalinks in AJAX requests. And in case of just have the permalink try to find their id using [url_to_postid()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) and work with it. (As you already know that works well with post ids)

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have changed little code this may work for u.

```
function AjaxRequest(section,divName)
{

<?php global $wpdb; ?>

             var pageurl = "<?php echo get_option('sitgeurl'); ?>/ajaxrequest.php?section="+section+"&divName="+divName;         
            //alert(pageurl);   

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                         document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML='';             
                    document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",pageurl,true);
            xmlhttp.send();             

}
```

Comment: I am calling the Ajax file from Ajax.js